# passing array containing list of urls to shell_exec function in php

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am creating a code that contain shell script in PHP.

When I try to run using `shell_execute` I am not getting actual result.

Here's my code:

```
  for($i;$i<5;){
      $output = shell_exec('./url_integrity_check.sh ' ."'echo $test[$i]'" );
      $i++;
  }
```

`$test` is the array that contain the list of values.

When I run this code it takes only `$test[0]` means top value of array every time, but I want it to loop through all the values of array and execute the shell script each time it increments the value of `$i`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($i=0;$i<5; $i++){

 $url = "./url_integrity_check.sh " . $test[$i];

 $output = shell_exec($url);

}
```